# Project a single column of a table filtered by tag from act as taggale

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, arel, act-as-taggable-on

Currently the only way I know to sub select in rails is with arel,
for exmaple -

```
sub = x.where(y:'x').project(:id)
select = a.where(a[:x_id].in(sub))
```

question is, 
if x is using the acts as taggable on gem and need to filtered by a specific tag, use with `tagged_with` method.

How can I still achive same database efficiency, it looks like the `tagged with` method override the projection.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Arel to build sub selects in Rails:

```
sub = X.where(y: 'x')
select = A.where(x_id: sub)
```

generates the following SQL, assuming A's table name is `as` and X's is `xs`:

```
SELECT "as".* FROM "as" WHERE "as"."x_id" IN (SELECT "xs"."id" FROM "xs" WHERE "xs"."y" = 'x')
```

Testing with `tagged_with` worked: `A.where(x_id: X.tagged_with('my_tag'))` generates the expected SQL, at least for Rails 5.1, version on which I've tested.

*Edit*

You can specify the column used inside the subselect if needed. If you don't specify it, the primary key column is the default:

```
sub = X.where(y: 'x').select(:x_y_id)
select = A.where(x_id: sub)
```

will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "as".* FROM "as" WHERE "as"."x_id" IN (SELECT "xs"."x_y_id" FROM "xs" WHERE "xs"."y" = 'x')
```

Comment: Looks like this works, What if the wanted column is not the id one ? lets say its x_y_id , will I need to add another query ?